# Inner shadow on UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, xamarin, calayer, uicollectionviewcell

I have created a nice looking collection view with image cells inside. I wanted the cells to be round so I made maskToBounds equal to true and set the corner radius to half of the image's width. This all works fine but now I want to add shadow effects to the cells and there are 2 problems:

1. I want to have an outer shadow on some of the cells (which is currently being cropped off because I set masktoBounds to true...
2. I want t have an inner shadow effect on some other cells (they are supposed to look less highlighted), but I don't even know how to make an inner shadow...

Any help desperately appreciated,
I work with C# in Xamarin.iOS by the way, but I will also understand any other language.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the UIView.Layer.ShadowX and play with the values of it I recommend to use an image instead to simulate the effect because the Layer effects will kill your device processor

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the XamSvg component. You create 2 svg with a gradient to mimics an inset and an outset. As it is an svg, it is stretchable and could be set as your cell's background to simulate your shadow.